# automatic alignment of buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml

I got 4 buttons aligned inside a grid. Is there any way to make alignment automatic so that if one button's visibility is set to false the remaining buttons uses the space wisely[other buttons moves to accommodate into new space]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a grid, put the buttons in a StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal".  Also, make sure you set your button Visibility to "Collapsed" instead of "Hidden".

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="1" Width="50" Height="23" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Button Content="2" Width="50" Height="23"/>
        <Button Content="3" Width="50" Height="23" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Button Content="4" Width="50" Height="23"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Or this:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="1" Width="50" Height="23" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="2" Width="50" Height="23"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="3" Width="50" Height="23" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="4" Content="4" Width="50" Height="23"/>
</Grid>
```

You should see the buttons centered but only show the second and fourth button

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the layout and how complex you want the space distribution to be, if a uniform distribution is enough you could use a [`UniformGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx), in a normal `Grid` that would be a bit tricky as the columns and rows need to be adjusted.